# forum data is not being send to xampp server despite code giving no errors

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

is my code alright like i checked my code multiple times still didn't see any errors and data is not being send to server side , im even getting message user register successful like i don't understand what could be the problem like its checking in database

```
my code below

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div class=" container">
        <?php 
        var_dump($_POST);
        if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
            $user_name =$_POST["user_name"];
            $email =$_POST["email"];
            $password =$_POST["password"];
            $reapeat_password =$_POST["reapeat_password"];
            $contact =$_POST["contact"];
            $passwordhash = password_hash( $password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT );
            $errors = array();

            if(empty($user_name) OR empty($email) OR empty($password) OR empty($reapeat_password) OR empty($contact)  ){
                array_push($errors,"all fileds are required");
            }
            if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
                array_push($errors,"email is not valid");
            }
            if(strlen($password)<9){
                array_push($errors,"paswword must be 9 chracter long");
            }
            if($password!==$reapeat_password){
                array_push($errors,"password does not match");
            }
            if(strlen($contact)<10){
                array_push($errors,"plase enter a right number");
            }
           
            require_once "../config file/config.php";

            // Check if email already exists
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email'";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            $rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
            if ($rowcount > 0) {
                array_push($errors, "Email already exists");
            }
                    
            // Check if contact already exists
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE contact = '$contact'";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            $rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
            if ($rowcount > 0) {
                array_push($errors, "Contact already exists");
            }

            // Check if username already exists
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = '$user_name'";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            $rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
            if ($rowcount > 0) {
                array_push($errors, "Username already exists");
            }
   

            

            if(count($errors)> 0){
                foreach($errors as $error){
                    echo"<div  class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>$error</div>";
            }
           }else{
            $sql ="INSERT INTO `users` (user_name,email,password ,contact) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
            $stmt =mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
            $preparestmt = mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,$sql);
            if ($preparestmt){
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"ssss", $user_name,$email,$passwordhash,$contact);
                mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                echo " <div  class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'> you are registered successfully </div>";
            } else{
                die("something went wrong");
            }
              
           }
        }

        ?>
        <form action="reister.php" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user name" placeholder="user name">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="email">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="password">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="reapeat_password" placeholder=" confirm password">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="contact" placeholder="contact">
            </div>

            <div class="form-btn">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="register"name="submit">
            </div>
        </form>
         <div><p>already  registered<a href="login.php">signin</a></p></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
my var dump data
Array ( [user_name] => lplpqw [email] => lplpqw@gmail.com [password] => 123456789098765432 [reapeat_password] => 123456789098765432 [contact] => 123456789098765432 [submit] => register ) database connection successful
```

i try looking var dump and print_r too see my data and console logs didn't see anything like all  my values are strings and everything what im thinking could it xampp issue like it happened to me before too with edit data it randomly stooped working then it was working,but i don't know reasons why it happened

Comment: `my var dump data`...this appears to show that the data _is_ being sent to the server successfully. Do you really mean that it isn't being saved to the database? Please clarify

Comment: And if so...have you got mysqli error reporting enabled? What version of php are you using?

Comment: @ADyson yes like its not being saved there

Comment: @ADyson my php version php -v
PHP 8.0.30 i check in xampp shell

Comment: @ADyson by mysqli error reporting if if you mean it will push error if data already and  things then kinda yes  rest nope but im kinda getting alert that i setup user registered successfully

Comment: By "mysqli error reporting" I mean the mysqli error reporting feature! https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli#connection . https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-report.php

Comment: @ADyson error is fixed randomly like its working now like do you know what could cause this issue like xampp stopped working then randomly starts working

Comment: It's more likely something specific about the data you entered. Computers aren't random in that way. And it's about mysql, not xampp. Xampp just installs php, mysql etc. It doesn't run your code

Comment: Anyway, enable the mysqli error reporting and you'll get an error message in php if the sql code crashes. Then you'll know what's wrong

Comment: idk man its like 2 time its happening to me before my like edit data from database stopped working then few days later it was working without me changing a single thing again this happened i probably doing something wrong

Comment: Maybe. But until you enable those errors you aren't going to know